# What are the differences in schemas of main directory servers?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openldap, opendirectory, directory-services

Active Directory, OpenLDAP or Apple's Open Directory have different schemas for holding user info and group membership. Having a Open Directory here I can say for example that user's Distinguished Name is attribute `dn`, while it seems to be `distinguishedName` for AD.

Is there a site that references how the main DS hold the info, and if not why not start to list them here? I searched for it but couldn't find it.

I'm looking for the following:

- User

  - distinguished name
  - email address
  - username (aka login)
  - real name (aka full name)
- Group

  - member list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to look at documentation from each vendor, and your own internal documentation as well.
LDAP schemas can be (and often are) extensively customized to meet local needs.

## For AD

[MSDN Topic (includes a list of classes/attributes)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675085%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

## For Open Directory/OS X

[There's a whole sub-chapter on Open Directory](http://help.apple.com/advancedserveradmin/mac/10.7/)

## LDAP In General

[This page has a good list](http://www.ldapman.org/ldap_rfcs.html) - See in particular:
[RFC 2256 (LDAP Schema)](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2256.txt)
[RFC 2307 (LDAP as a Network Information Service](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2307.txt)
[RFC 4519 (Even More LDAP Schema Extensions)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4519)
If you use `sudo` [there are LDAP extensions for that too](http://www.gratisoft.us/sudo/sudoers.ldap.man.html)